# Problema com Navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

Tenho um problema com a questão da navbar.
Estou a fazer 1 template porem encontro-me com o seguinte erro.
[image: não Erro]

Como podem ver no lado direito o scroll esta no topo mas assim que vou descendo acontece-me isto:[image: Erro]  a navbar fica a meio do ecrã como se estivesse la fixa.

o que eu queria era a barra inicialmente (imagem 1) estivesse igual porem assim que fosse descendo acontece-se uma transição suave da navbar para cima e vice versa quando voltasse.
alguma sugestão estou todo a ouvidos pois sou 1 pouco iniciante nesta matéria de fazer templates.

obrigado desde já a colaboração de todos.

### Cabeçalhos

Comment: Tem como colocar o css?

Comment: http://kopy.io/S4ObM 

peço desculpa pela demora

Comment: código utilizado por favor.

Comment: penso que se refere a isto Edilson http://kopy.io/KeejJ

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver usando o bootstrap utilize.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

E se não tiver recomendo da uma olhada ajuda bastante.

Comment: não funciona pois estou a utilizar materialize mas obrigado pelo seu tempo :)

Comment: Desculpe novo nesta área.

Comment: não tem problema também sou